# How to display HTML's contents as a group on colorbox jQuery?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

[I know how to display images as a group.](http://jsfiddle.net/UFtrK/112/)

And I know how to display one HTML content:

```
$.colorbox({html:"<h1>Welcome</h1>"});
```

But, is there a way to make slides of HTML contents, like with images?

Example:

```
<div>block 1 data (1st slide's data)</div>
<div>block 2 data (2nd slide's data)</div>
<div>block 3 data (3rd slide's data)</div>
...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFtrK/519/)

Is it possible to slide from one block to another like with images?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Colorbox lets you by default cycle trough the images when you click on them. Do you mean that you want to change this behavior and then let the images slide on click?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want the same behaviour but for custom html blocks. I want to be able to slide html blocks as it where images.

Comment: I think you know that colorbox has the option: slideshow:true.

Comment: @Franco I updated my question. Please, can you check it one more time and lemme know if it's not clear enough

Comment: Please it will be much better and clear if you keep the code in your fiddle as reference, o I can follow along.

Comment: @Franco Sorry, you're right. I added new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UFtrK/519/

Answer (score 0):

`cbox_complete` does the trick.

> `cbox_complete` - triggers when the transition has completed and the
>   newly loaded content has been revealed.

```
$(document).on('cbox_complete', function(){
  var htmlData = '<div> some html data goes here </div>';
  $('#cboxLoadedContent').html(htmlData);
});
```